# How can we find if a video contains Audio or not in Android

Tags: android, video

How can we find if a video contains Audio or not in Android

Is there any way in Android to find if a video contains audio

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes. It is possible. You need to look into the [MediaMetadataRetriever](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMetadataRetriever.html)

By using `METADATA_KEY_HAS_AUDIO` you can check whether the video has the audio or not.

```
private boolean isVideoHaveAudioTrack(String path) {
        boolean audioTrack =false;

        MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
        retriever.setDataSource(path);
        String hasAudioStr = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_AUDIO);
        if(hasAudioStr!=null && hasAudioStr.equals("yes")){ 
         audioTrack=true; } 
        else{ 
        audioTrack=false; }

        return audioTrack;
    }
```

Here path is your video file path.

Comment: there is a bit of change in this code this should be  if(hasAudioStr.equals("yes")) {
            audioTrack=true;
        }
        else{
            audioTrack=false;
        }

Comment: Thanks for initiating. I updated my answer. Cheers !

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to [@KingofMasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46483029/8199772) answer, if the file doesn't have a audio file then `String hasAudioStr` will return null. The string will then through a `nullpointerexception`.

here is how I resolved this:

```
private boolean doesVideoHaveAudioTrack(String path) {
    boolean audioTrack;

    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    retriever.setDataSource(path);
    String hasAudioStr = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_AUDIO);
    if (hasAudioStr==null){
        audioTrack = false;
    }else {
        audioTrack = true;
    }

    return audioTrack;
}
```

All credit goes to @KingofMasses, I just wanted to point out the issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the return value and pointing for the nullpointexception. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

more simple, null pointer exception safe

```
boolean hasAudio = "yes".equals(retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_HAS_AUDIO));
```